# Why am I getting the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string' when calling this method in my Web Service?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, methods

So the issue I'm having is that when I call a method inside of my WCF service reference, I get the red underlined code "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'". Initially, I assumed I has accidentally set the webservice method to `public void GetData()` However upon further review, I know it isn't. The WCF method I m trying to call is:

```
    public string GetData()
    {
       return "StringRecieved";
    }
```

The Operation contract is defined as this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
        public interface IService1
        {
            [OperationContract]
            string GetData(); 
        }
```

And the place I'm calling the method is in a different application.

```
    Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration();
        Service1Client service1Client;
        service1Client = new Service1Client(endpointConfiguration);

        string Data = service1Client.GetDataAsync(); //This is where I'm getting my error.
```

Why am I getting that error? The method is set as a string and I'm trying to assign it to a string.

Comment: `string GetData()` or `Senator[] GetData();`? Which of them is the correct one? Have you confirmed the client has the latest code generated?

Comment: Well obviously the `GetDataAsync` method doesn't return anything (i.e. it is `void`) but you're expecting it to be a string.

Comment: It's string GetData(). I forgot to change the Operation Contract I posted here because I had to modify exactly what it was. I've also check to confirm the client had the latest generated code by updating the Service Reference.

Comment: @DavidG where is it set to void? Or how is it set to void? In what way can I set it to return a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for async you need add event GetDataCompleted and method.

```
service1Client.GetDataCompleted += service1Client_GetDataCompleted;
public void service1Client_GetDataCompleted(object sender, wsService1.GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string Data = e.Result.ToString();
}
```